# Kubernetes (microk8s) vs Traditional Docker Host Machine Architecture

Tags: microk8s

I tried to find the answer in previous post, but i did not find it !

My question seems dumb, i'm just trying to figure it out :)

I'm new to docker and kubernetes, i'm trying to understand the architecture of kubernetes cluster, nodes, and pods.

I'm using two machines with docker installed, each machine have two containers running, i want to install MicroK8s to start playing with kubernetes, my questions are :

1. As below image >  Can I install it on separate machine and connect it to my docker host machines so it will manage my containers their with support of some sort of (agent/ maybe services) ?, Or kubernetes/MicroK8s must be installed on the machine that will host the containers  ?
2. Can i add my running docker containers directly to a pod ? or i must re-create them ?

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can play with any VM software(cpu virtualization required).
You can set up 3 VMs(master, node1,node2). You have to install kubernetes in each VM. When you connect them thru calico they communicate each other. When you make pods with app or db , you can loadbalance to node1 and node2 or more from master. Then you can create a service to export route to the pods. Or If you want to run everything in one big server, you can. Horizontal scaling or vertical scaling is your choice.

2. you cant mount a running docker container to the pod but you can load a docker image from any registry.